# Load UITableView from nib into ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I've created

1. Cocoa Touch Class subClass of UITableViewCell with .xib file
2. UIView ( .xib file) and placed UITableView into that view and give it a UIView Class
3. Now i want link that UITableViewCell with UTableView (which is in UIView *.xib file) and then load this view into a viewController.
4. A generalViewController loads first then it adds personSubView of UIVIew in that There is tableView and it loads another personCellView in personSubView. 
   can someone suggest me where to go from here?
   Thanks

Comment: You can create custom cell

Comment: this is what i did, created custom cell through nib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register the cell in tableview then you can use as normal.

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: yourNibCellClass.self), bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourNibCellIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Cell**

You should register your xib file in order to use it in tableView:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "YourCustomCellXibName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCustomCellReuseIdentifier")
    }
```

for nib name you can use (less errors in the future):

```
String(describing: YourCustomCellClass.self)
```

in UITebleViewDataSource method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCustomCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCuctomCellClass
    return cell
}
```

**2. TableView**

```
/*  Load tableView from xib */

/*  During the loading process, this method unarchives object,
    initializes it, sets its properties to it's configured values,
    and reestablishes any connections to other objects
 */
let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewXibName", owner:self, options: nil)

/* Check if we don't get a nil */
if let tableView: CustomTableView = nib?.first as? CustomTableView {

    /* Add tableView to the viewcontroller */
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```